# Pentaho GC overhead in "Text File Input" with large file

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, pentaho

I'm a little stuck here. I need to read a very large CSV file (42.000 lines with 180 columns). CSV has a header.

Everytime **"Text file input"** step tries to load this file, after a while Pentaho finishes processing because of the lack of heap space and GC working at 98% of CPU.

When I read the following file (much smaller):

[image]

I get this result for every line:

[image]

How can I read a large CSV file using **"Text File input"** step without using so much memory space? Is it possible to read small batches each time?

I know **"CSV input"** step can read batches of lines, but the result is different:

[image]

Is it possible to get the same result like **"Text file input"** using this step?

Some more data:

- I'm using Pentaho 8.1 with Xms2048m y Xmx6144m values in JVM. I can't go further than that.
- CSV columns and names are dynamic.

Thank you!!!

PD 1: [CSV file (partial)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZDEX1KlaTDFosfd4EsvkoKDlmiC3BJi/view?usp=sharing)
PD 2: [Transformation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrJKkPJfnzcfkvfE_dNSwMtsnK52-ycR/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: As your configuration is fixed "Xms2048m y Xmx6144m values in JVM", Thus right now you have 2 option. One is look **NIO buffer size** and another is **Running in parallel**. Anyways. Also. there might have some issue in your other steps in the transformation make this problem. Can you please share your transformation with your CSV file with few records?

Comment: @Runa Thank you for your response.

I've added the transformation and a reduced CSV file. Transformation has a JS step, wich marks some rows in the CSV file, and uses a lot of memory too.

Comment: thanks for your files. I personally process csv file containing around 20 million rows. Ok. I will look your transformation and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, @Runa ! I really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'CSV file input' instead of 'Text file Input'. And also require to configure below options

1. Set **NIO buffer size to like 50000** (Specify the size of the read buffer, the number of bytes that is read at one time from the source.)
2. Check **Running in parallel** option . And also, **change number of start copy** to 3/5 [Right click on CSV file input step]

I have run your transformation with your file with (50 thousand line) and configuration is [-Xms2048m" "-Xmx3072m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m]. And also i have removed  your JS step for test purpose . Also I don't know why you use cartesian Join here?. But found its working properly . [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OhN9bX-9AegFyM-llDJn6tTgcJvxP-II?usp=sharing).

[image]

Comment: ! Finally, I solved the problem. Java Script step had three variables that were constants instead. So that only change solved the excesive use of RAM.